# CRM 2011 Reference ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx in custom aspx

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, xrm

I have a custom aspx page that needs to be iframed in crm. I'm in need to use Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm in the custom aspx because i wanted to open entity record in CRM web client/outlook from my custom page. Is it possible to reference ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx in my custom aspx page? What's the best approach for this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 1):

From [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602956.aspx) : "You can use them in form scripts or in ribbon commands. For HTML web resources, they are available when you include the ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx page."
So you have two options:

- Use Webresources (Silverlight or HTML)
- Use [window.open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328483.aspx)

Comment: I used the approach of postMessage and receieveMessage.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff800814.aspx